# Gradle plugin library logging

Tags: logging, gradle

I have a Gradle project that uses a plugin I have written. That plugin uses an external library (jar) that logs using java.util.logging.

My problem is that when I build my project Gradle doesn't show all log [Level](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/logging/Level.html)s (even when run with --debug).

For example, if I run my Gradle build with --debug I see messages from the library logged with `log.debug()` but don't see messages logged with `log.fine()`, `log.finer()` or `log.finest()`.

The Gradle [docs](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/logging.html) suggest adding `logging.captureStandardOutput LogLevel.DEBUG` but this still doesn't seem to capture `fine`, `finer` or `finest`.

I can't change the external library code.

Is there a way to display these finer log levels during my build?

Gradle version info:

```
------------------------------------------------------------
Gradle 1.6
------------------------------------------------------------

Gradle build time: Tuesday, 7 May 2013 09:12:14 o'clock UTC
Groovy: 1.8.6
Ant: Apache Ant(TM) version 1.8.4 compiled on May 22 2012
Ivy: 2.2.0
JVM: 1.7.0_17 (Oracle Corporation 23.7-b01)
OS: Linux 3.8.0-35-generic amd64
```

Answer (score 3):

I don't think there is a way to capture `fine`, `finer` and `finest` log outputs. The mapping of log levels is fixed, and cannot be changed. `logging.captureStandardOutput` is for standard output, not for log output.

Comment: Thanks, Peter. So am I right in thinking that log.debug, log.info are mapped but other log levels aren't? And that they can't be manually mapped? Just trying to understand why I see some logging levels from the library but not others.

Comment: That's my understanding.

Comment: Would that be classed as a bug/feature request on Gradle?